# In Android, how to distinguish between multiple instances of the same widget?

Tags: android

I'm making a widget. It will random a number when clicked. When I add multiple of this widget on home screen, they start to generate random number at the same time when clicked. What I want is when a widget is clicked it only updates itself and non of the others around it. Please, help me.
My code: class UpdateWidgetService

```
@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
    // create some random data
    AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(this.getApplicationContext());
    int[] allWidgetIds = intent.getIntArrayExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS);
    for (int widgetId : allWidgetIds) {
        // create some random data
        int number = (new Random().nextInt(100));

        RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(this.getApplicationContext().getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_layout);
        Log.w("WidgetExample", String.valueOf(number));
        // Set the text
        remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.update, "Random: " + String.valueOf(number));

        // Register an onClickListener
        Intent clickIntent = new Intent(this.getApplicationContext(), MyWidgetProvider.class);
        clickIntent.setAction(AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE);
        clickIntent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS, widgetId);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), widgetId, clickIntent, 0);
        remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.btn_update, pendingIntent);
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(widgetId, remoteViews);
    }
    stopSelf();
    super.onStart(intent, startId);
}
```

class MyWidgetProvider:

```
@Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
    Log.w(LOG, "onUpdate method called");
    // Get all ids
    ComponentName thisWidget = new ComponentName(context, MyWidgetProvider.class);
    int[] allWidgetIds = appWidgetManager.getAppWidgetIds(thisWidget);

    // Build the intent to call the service
    Intent intent = new Intent(context.getApplicationContext(), UpdateWidgetService.class);
    intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS, allWidgetIds);

    // Update the widgets via the service
    context.startService(intent);
}
```

Comment: i tried it too and came to the conclusion that it is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Each of your widgets is identified by a specific ID. Your `UpdateWidgetService` class looks like it is correctly looping over the ID's.

The issue is in your `MyWidgetProvider.onUpdate()` method. This code is wrong:

```
// Get all ids
ComponentName thisWidget = new ComponentName(context, MyWidgetProvider.class);
int[] allWidgetIds = appWidgetManager.getAppWidgetIds(thisWidget);
```

The comment explains why it is wrong - it gets **all** the widget ID's.

---

Look at the parameters in your `onUpdate()` method:

- `public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds)`

Here you can see an array of widget ID's is given to you, and you must pass this array to your update service:

- `int[] appWidgetIds`

So your code should end up looking something like this:

```
@Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
    Log.w(LOG, "onUpdate method called");

    // Build the intent to call the service
    Intent intent = new Intent(context.getApplicationContext(), UpdateWidgetService.class);
    intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS, appWidgetIds);

    // Update the widgets via the service
    context.startService(intent);
}
```

That way you are only updating the widgets that the system sends to you, instead of updating all of them each time.