# Trouble with my widget service

Tags: android, android-widget, android-service, android-broadcast

I have been working on an appwidget for the past day or so and I think I have followed everything correctly but for some reason my update service just doesnt seem to be working.

Let me past my code, Im sorry its quite abit. But that's what's needed to get the widget up and running.

MyWidgetProvider:

```
 public class MyWidgetProvider extends AppWidgetProvider {

private static final String LOG = "$AppWidgetProvider";

@Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {

    Log.i(LOG, "onUpdate method called");

    // Get all ids
    ComponentName thisWidget = new ComponentName(context, MyWidgetProvider.class);
    int[] allWidgetIds = appWidgetManager.getAppWidgetIds(thisWidget);

    // Build the intent to call the service
    Intent intent = new Intent(context.getApplicationContext(), UpdateWidgetService.class);
    intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS, allWidgetIds);

    // Update the widgets via the service
    context.startService(intent);
}
}
```

My XML provider

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appwidget-provider xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:initialLayout="@layout/widget_layout"
    android:minHeight="200dp"
    android:minWidth="144dp"
    android:widgetCategory="home_screen"
    android:configure="widget.AppWidgetConfigureActivity"
    android:updatePeriodMillis="5000" >
</appwidget-provider>
```

Manifest file:

```
<!-- Widget -->
    <receiver
        android:name="widget.MyWidgetProvider"
        android:icon="@drawable/fsk"
        android:label="FSK Widget" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
            android:resource="@xml/app_widget_provider_info" />
    </receiver>
   <!-- Services -->
    <service android:name=".widget.UpdateWidgetService" >
    </service>
```

My AppWidgetConfiguration Class:

```
public class AppWidgetConfigureActivity extends Activity {

public String TAG = "AppWidgetConfigureActivity";
private View emptyView;
private View noDevices;
private int appWidgetId;
public static MyDevicesSpinnerAdapter myDeviceAdapter;
private Spinner myDevicesSpinner;
private Spinner updateFreqSpinner;
private Button configureButton;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if (!isLoggedIn()) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(AppWidgetConfigureActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("Source", "widgetConfig");
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    getWidgetId();
    setTitle(R.string.title_activity_app_widget_configure);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_app_widget_configure);

    Intent cancelResultValue = new Intent();
    cancelResultValue.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, appWidgetId);
    setResult(RESULT_CANCELED, cancelResultValue);
    myDevicesSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.widget_configure_devices_spinner);
    updateFreqSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.widget_configure_updateFreq_spinner);
    myDeviceAdapter = new MyDevicesSpinnerAdapter(AppWidgetConfigureActivity.this);
    myDevicesSpinner.setAdapter(myDeviceAdapter);

    getMyDevices();
    populateFreqSpinner();
    configureButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.widget_configure_configure_button);
    iAgreeCheckBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.widget_configure_iAgree_checkbox);

}

    private void getWidgetId() {
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {
        appWidgetId = extras.getInt(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID);
    }
}


public void onConfigureClicked(View view) {

    SaveWidgetConfiguration();

    // Update the View
    AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(AppWidgetConfigureActivity.this);
    RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(AppWidgetConfigureActivity.this.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_layout);
    appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);

    // End the config
    Intent resultValue = new Intent();
    resultValue.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, appWidgetId);
    setResult(RESULT_OK, resultValue);
    finish();
}   

/**
 * Saves the configs of the widget
 */
private void SaveWidgetConfiguration() {

    int deviceTypeId = 0;
    int deviceId = 0;
    String hashedPasscode = "";
    int updateFreq = 30000;

    SharedPreferences prefs = AppWidgetConfigureActivity.this.getSharedPreferences("prefs", 0);
    SharedPreferences.Editor edit = prefs.edit();
    edit.putInt("Widget_DeviceTypeId:" + appWidgetId, deviceTypeId);
    edit.putInt("Widget_DeviceId:" + appWidgetId, deviceId);
    edit.putString("Widget_Passcode:" + appWidgetId, hashedPasscode);
    edit.putInt("Widget_UpdateFreq:" + appWidgetId, updateFreq);
    edit.commit();
}
}
```

My UpdateWidget Service:

```
public class UpdateWidgetService extends Service {

private static final String LOG = "$widgetUpdateService";   

@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {

    Log.i(LOG, "Called and started");

    AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(this.getApplicationContext());
    int[] allWidgetIds = intent.getIntArrayExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS);

    ComponentName thisWidget = new ComponentName(getApplicationContext(), MyWidgetProvider.class);
    int[] allWidgetIds2 = appWidgetManager.getAppWidgetIds(thisWidget);
    Log.w(LOG, "From Intent" + String.valueOf(allWidgetIds.length));
    Log.w(LOG, "Direct" + String.valueOf(allWidgetIds2.length));

    for (int appWidgetId : allWidgetIds) {
        // create some random data
        RemoteViews remoteView = getView(this, appWidgetId, allWidgetIds);
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, remoteView);
    }
    stopSelf();
    super.onStart(intent, startId);
}

private RemoteViews getView(Context context, int appWidgetId, int[] allWidgetIds) {
    WidgetPrefs prefs = getWidgetConfiguration(context, appWidgetId);
    switch (prefs.deviceTypeId) {
    case 8: {
        int number = (new Random().nextInt(100));

        RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(this.getApplicationContext().getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_layout);
        Log.w("WidgetExample", String.valueOf(number));
        // Set the text
        remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.widget_textview_gpscoords, "Random: " + String.valueOf(number));
        // Register an onClickListener
        Intent clickIntent = new Intent(this.getApplicationContext(), MyWidgetProvider.class);
        clickIntent.setAction(AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE);
        clickIntent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS, allWidgetIds);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 0, clickIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.widget_button_dissarm, pendingIntent);
    }
        break;
    case 10: {
    }
        break;
    default: {
        // Error
    }
    }

    return null;
}

/**
 * Gets the preferences of the widget
 */
private WidgetPrefs getWidgetConfiguration(Context context, int appWidgetId) {

    WidgetPrefs wPrefs = new WidgetPrefs();
    SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences("prefs", 0);
    wPrefs.deviceTypeId = prefs.getInt("Widget_DeviceTypeId:" + appWidgetId, wPrefs.deviceTypeId);
    wPrefs.deviceId = prefs.getInt("Widget_DeviceId:" + appWidgetId, wPrefs.deviceId);
    wPrefs.hashedPasscode = prefs.getString("Widget_Passcode:" + appWidgetId, wPrefs.hashedPasscode);
    wPrefs.updateFreq = prefs.getInt("Widget_UpdateFreq:" + appWidgetId, wPrefs.updateFreq);
    return wPrefs;
}

/**
 * Holder class to store widget preferences
 * 
 */
private class WidgetPrefs {
    public int deviceTypeId = -1;
    public int deviceId = -1;
    public String hashedPasscode = "";
    public int updateFreq = 30000;
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}
```

}

Now the issue I am having, is that all my break point or Logs in my service never get hit or don't appear in my logcat, when I add the widget it gives me the config activity I set it up and it then displays the widget. But if i click on it or anything. I never get any activity out of my service?

What Am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seem to be 2 issues in your `UpdateWidgetService.getView()` method.

---

1)

You register a click listener on your widget with the following code:

```
// Register an onClickListener
Intent clickIntent = new Intent(this.getApplicationContext(), MyWidgetProvider.class);
clickIntent.setAction(AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE);
clickIntent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS, allWidgetIds);
```

When the widget is clicked, it will broadcast an intent for your `MyWidgetProvider` class - this is not an activity.

Replace that with the name of your activity that you want to launch.

---

2)

Just below that code, you set up your `PendingIntent` like this:

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 0,
    clickIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

The problem is that you are sending a general broadcast by using `PendingIntent.getBroadcast()`.

You should be setting up to start an activity by using `PendingIntent.getActivity()` instead. Something like this:

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0,
    clickIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

Of course, also make sure that your activity is registered in your manifest file, otherwise it will not launch.

---

By the way I see that your `MyWidgetProvider.onUpdate()` method attempts to update all widgets at the same time, instead of updating each one on its own. I have an answer on a similar question that uses the same code as you, and you might find it interesting:

- [In Android, how to distinguish between multiple instances of the same widget?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23698325/383414)

And in another answer, I provide links to a very simple widget demo app that you could find useful to learn from:

- [How to create a custom lock screen widget](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23697807/383414)